# Changing settings of an existing kendo treeview (loadondemand)

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

tell me please, how can I change properties of an existing kendo treeview on the fly.

For example, I've created a treeview:

```
container.kendoTreeView({
    dataSource: dataSource,
    checkboxes: {
        checkChildren: true
    },
    loadOnDemand: false,
    template: kendo.template(itemTemplate)
});
```

and want to change its **loadOnDemand** property like this:

```
container.data("kendoTreeView").set({
    loadOnDemand: false
})
```

as in some other plugins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot. You need to re-initialize the whole TreeView. If loadOnDemand is set to false initially, setting it to true would not make a difference, the records are already fetched anyway.

Comment: It is necessary when I change dataSource on the fly to local array and want to expand whole tree. Even with local data only first level nodes are added to DOM after changing dataSource, other are being added only after clicking arrow. That's why treeview.expand('.k-item') does not work. But if the treeview was initialized with loadondemand = false all nodes are added at once.

Comment: Solved using expanded = true for all items.